# Saving and loading control values when switching between different User Controls in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls

I have a splitcontainer. In Panel 1 I have 7 toolstripbuttons that opens a User Control in Panel 2 when I click on them. The user control consists of different textboxes that the user can fill in. The code looks like this:

```
private void toolStripButtonBaseLayers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
    BaseLayers BL = new BaseLayers();
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(BL);
}

private void toolStripButtonSpatialCoverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
    SpatialCoverage SC = new SpatialCoverage();
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(SC);
}

private void toolStripButtonFloodMaps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
    FloodMaps FM = new FloodMaps();
    splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(FM);
}
```

Now everytime I open another user control with the click event the user control will be empty because I clear the panel and open a new User Control. This is not what I want to do!

My question is how it is possible to save everything you filled in in the textboxes? And how it is possible that all the user control values will be still filled in when switching between them? For example I fill the user control BaseLayers in, I switch to the user control Spatial Coverage and Flood Maps and when I swith back to the user control BaseLayers everything still have to be filled in.

Comment: Using Controls.Clear() is *very* dangerous, it does not dispose the controls that are removed.  They will cause a leak for the lifetime of the app.  But it so happens that it is *exactly* what you seem to want.  You'll have to keep track of their reference so you can avoid creating a new instance and simply reuse the existing one.

Comment: Is possible in the loading and closing event for the User Control? Or how do you see it?

Answer (score 0):

Create all your controls and hide all of them(`Visible=false`). Then in Click-Events just set `Visible=true` for the appropriate control.

Example:

```
private void toolStripButtonFloodMaps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetChildVisibleForPanel(typeof(FloodMaps), splitContainer1.Panel2);
}

static void SetChildVisibleForPanel(Type visChildType, Panel pnl)
{
    if (pnl.Controls.Count==0)
    {
        //Create your controls with Visible=false;
    }
    foreach (Control ctl in pnl.Controls)
    {
        ctl.Visible = (ctl.GetType() == visChildType);
    }
}
```